# Android application Responsive(Fit for all screen sizes)

Tags: java, android, layout, android-linearlayout

I am developing an android application,That has a buttons and images.I need to make it responsive.If i use bigger devices like tablets,it displays the controls very small.And when i used in landscape mode,it displays half of the controls or items.How can i overcome this and make my application responsive to all devices.I attached one of my  XML code below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    >        
</ImageView>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layButtonH"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/addnew"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="    ADD NEW     "
     android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/open"
         android:background="@drawable/button_shape_cancel"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="        OPEN         "
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/Register"
         android:background="@drawable/button_shape_cancel"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"  
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="       LOGIN        "
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start off with below mentioned resources. Making an app available for all screen sizes needs certain consideration while designing and developing the app.

You will have to work on your images to make them consistent with different screen sizes. This will solve the issue with very small controls in tablets.

Also, it looks like in landscape mode your widgets are going beyond the screen height. A quick solution would be to put the `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView` so that it scrolls when in landscape and you see all of your controls. But ideal way would be to have different layouts for landscape and portrait modes.

If you use ScrolLView the code will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Your remaining xml elements -->

</ScrollView>
```

Ref:

1. [Design for multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)
2. [Supporting different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)
3. [Supporting multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design take 
1) Don't give hard code values like as 125dp rather than user wrap_content or match_parent property 
2) Put images under res drawable as per resolution OS take images suited for its resolution, e.g for tablet design create drawable-sw600 folder under res and put tablet images under it.
3) Same for values->dimension create different dimens file with specific folder name. e.g values-sw600 which is used for tablet
4) Use ScrollView control for avoiding screen cutting in landscape mode.
For more details and guideline please visit http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html